# How to change syntax for color and fill color in tkz-eulide

Tags: color, tkz-euclide, points

In tkz-euclide, points are filled in grey with a black outline. I can setup points to be completely black by using

```
\tkzSetUpPoint[fill=black]
```

Now what I would like to have a new keyword `rot` so that when I type

```
\tkzDrawPoint[red](P)
```

it is equal to typing

```
\tkzDrawPoint[color=red,fill=red](P)
```

The Problem I see here, is that red is defined and works for example for

```
\tkzDrawSegment[red](P_1,P_2)
\tkzLabelSegment[red](P_1,P_2){$s$}
```

MWE:

```
\documentclass{standalone}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{tkz-euclide}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
  \tkzDefPoint(0,0){P_1} \tkzDefPoint(1,0){P_2}
  \tkzDrawPoint(P_1)
  \tkzDrawPoint[red](P_2)
  \tkzLabelSegment[red](P_1,P_2){$s$}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

Comment: please, change title of your question to something like: "How to change syntax for color and fill color in tkz-eulide". now it is misleading.

Answer (score 4):

correct syntax for change color of points is for example `\tkzDrawPoint[color=red](P_2)` (for red point border) or `\tkzDrawPoints[fill=blue!30](P_2, P_3)` for changing fill (observe how is defined color). so try:

```
\documentclass{standalone}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{tkz-euclide}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
  \tkzDefPoint(0,0){P_1} \tkzDefPoint(1,0){P_2} \tkzDefPoint(2,0){P_3}
  \tkzDrawPoint(P_1)
  \tkzDrawPoints[color=red](P_2)          % <---
  \tkzDrawPoints[color=red,fill=red](P_3) % <---
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Sorry, that was an error on my part. But this changes things quite a bit, I will update the question accordingly.

Comment: you can't/should not change package syntax ... but you  can define new command with name not used in package ...

Comment: I am not trying to change the syntax of the package, just of the points so that it is actually coherent with things like labels and lines. I am aware that there are other things like the `fill` option for `\tkzMarkAngle` or `\tkzDrawPolygon`, and those I don't want to affect.

Answer (score 0):

So here is my temporary solution to this.

```
\makeatletter
\pgfkeys{drawpoint/.cd,
  red/.style={color=red,fill=red}
}
\pgfkeys{/tikz/.cd,
  red/.style={color=red},
  Red/.style={color=red,fill=red!30,opacity=0.3},
}
\makeatother
```

This now allows the use of those there defined colors not only for the command like `\tkzDrawSegment` but also for `\tkzDrawPoint` and `\tkzDrawCircle`

Example:

```
\documentclass{standalone}
\usepackage{tkz-euclide}
\usetkzobj{all}

\makeatletter
\pgfkeys{drawpoint/.cd,
  red/.style={color=red,fill=red}
}
\pgfkeys{/tikz/.cd,
  red/.style={color=red},
  Red/.style={color=red,fill=red!30,opacity=0.3},
}
\makeatother

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
  \tkzDefPoints{0.5/0.5/A,1.5/0.5/B,1.5/1.5/C,0.5/1.5/D,1/1/M}
  \tkzDrawPoint[red](M)
  \tkzDrawPolygon(A,B,C,D)
  \tkzMarkAngle[Red,size=0.3cm](D,C,B)
  \tkzDrawCircle[Red](A,M)
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image: solution]